# Google Chrome on Mac Google websites very small (zoomed out)

Tags: macos, google-chrome

This is the strangest thing but I got on my Mac this morning and fired up Chrome and for some reason any google related site is showing up extremely small. See the below images. Any idea what is going on? I've tried resetting the browser...no other websites seem to be behaving this way

[image]

[image]

Comment: what happens if you press `command and 0(zero)` ? It should reset to default page size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in any browsers, page zoom size's is also controlled by shortcuts keys:

- Zoom in : <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>
- Zoom out : <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>
- Default Zoom 100% : <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

You must have accidently pressed the zoom out key combinations. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
 to reset to the actual size, press and hold <kbd>command</kbd> on a Mac while pressing <kbd>0</kbd>

You can check whether a web page is set to its default zoom size, by seeing in the URL , near by the bookmark star symbol, it is displayed as a lens.